# Swift FBSDK Graph Request - An active access token must be used

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

I started getting this error only once I upgraded to xCode 9. Before then I never had this issue, and nothing was changed. When I make a graph request, I get the following error:

```
- some: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=An active access token must be used to query information about the current user., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=2500, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            "fbtrace_id" = HV5mzgqALtD;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}} #0
```

I'm not sure why I would be getting an error about the access code, I do include it, it wasn't an issue before, it was getting passed to Firebase just fine. I've updated all of my pods, tried cleaning the build, double checked my Facebook dev account, double checked the config of the FBSDK in xCode, everything I can think of.

Here is my Graph Request:

```
func fetchFacebookInfoForFirstTimeUser(_ firebaseUser:User) {
        print("fetchFacebookInfoForFirstTimeUser")


        let params = ["fields": "education, name, first_name, last_name, birthday, email, gender, locale, timezone, work, picture.type(large)"]
        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)

        _ = graphRequest?.start { [weak self] connection, result, error in
            guard let weakSelf = self else { return }

            // If something went wrong, we're logged out
            if (error != nil) {
                dump(error)
                return
            }
            // Whole bunch of stuff processing the data
    }
}
```

Here's all the code used to log into Facebook and Firebase:

```
/* ------------------ FACEBOOK -------------------- */
    /* ----------------------------------------------- */
    @objc func handleCustomFBLogin() {
        let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_location", "user_education_history", "user_work_history", "user_friends"]
        FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: permissions, from: self) {
            (result, err) in
                if err != nil {
                    print("FB Login Failed:", err!)
                    return
                } else {
                    print("FB Login Success!")

                    self.connectToFirebase()
                    Util.showLoadingIcon(uiView: self.view)
                }
        }
    }

    /* ------------------ FIREBASE ------------------ */
    /* --------------------------------------------- */
    func connectToFirebase() {
        print("connecting to Firebase")
        let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
        guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else { return }
        let credentials = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessTokenString)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
            // Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: "test@gmail.com", password: "111111", completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Something went wrong with our FB user:", error ?? "" )
                return
            }

            // Update FCM TOKEN
            var token = "A1"
            if let t = InstanceID.instanceID().token(){
                token = t
            }
            print("fcmToken: \(token)")
            let l = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users/\(user!.uid)")
            l.updateChildValues(["fcmToken": token])

            // Successfully logged in, let's move on
            print("Successfully logged into Firebase!")
            self.configureAppForUser(curUser: user!)
            print(user!.uid)
        })
    }

    func configureAppForUser(curUser: User) {
        // Grab the current user's data
       // self.pushDashboardViewController()
        print("configureAppForUser")
        ref.child("users").child(curUser.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.value is NSNull {
                print("First time user")
                // User does not have any data in Firebase, so get FB data and show onboarding
                self.fetchFacebookInfoForFirstTimeUser(curUser)
            } else {
                print("Existing user")
                let json = JSON(snapshot.value!)
                if json["onboarded"] == JSON.null || json["onboarded"] == false {
                     print("User has NOT onboarded")
                    // User has not onboarded, show onboarding screen
                    self.fetchFacebookInfoForFirstTimeUser(curUser)
                } else {
                    print("User HAS onboarded")
                    // User HAS onboarded, go to home screen
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "KnownUser\(String(describing: curUser.uid))")

                    self.pushDashboardViewController()
                }
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: No responses? Does anyone know how to solve this?